# Query common contacts (self many to many relationship) in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this classic scenario where I have a User table and a Contact table containing only UserId and ContactId columns (so it is a self many to many relationshsip). What I would like is a query that gives me a list of userIds with number of common contacts with the specified User. In plain old SQL I have the following query (contacts of user and user itself is filtered out to get facebook like friend suggestions):

```
SELECT COUNT(c1.ContactId) as CommonContact, c2.UserId
from Contacts as c1
inner join Contacts as c2 on c1.ContactId = c2.ContactId
Where c1.UserId = @Id AND c2.UserId != @Id 
AND c2.UserId NOT IN (SELECT ContactId from Contacts Where UserId = @Id)
Group By c2.UserId
ORDER BY CommonContact Desc
```

This simple query works great but I can not figure out how to write the same query in LINQ to Entity, because in the Entity Framework model I have User entity that entity have Contact navigation property but the connection table is not there directly....

Thanks a lot for any help...

Comment: I will suggest adding some identity field in your connection table that will make many to many into one to many and many to one relations and you will be able to query them nicely. In reality, there is never a truly many to many relation as we always have some extra attributes along with connection. Like when relation was created or updated and status of it, active, blocked etc.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have time and try to run it but something like this should work.

```
public class Test
    {
        //simulate an IQueryable
        private readonly IQueryable<Person> _people = new List<Person>().AsQueryable();

        public void FindContactMatchCount(Guid personId)
        {
            //we'll need the list of id's of the users contacts for comparison, we don't need to resolve this yet though so 
            //we'll leave it as an IQueryable and not turn it into a collection
            IQueryable<Guid> idsOfContacts = _people.Where(x => x.Id == personId).SelectMany(x => x.Contacts.Select(v => v.Id));

            //find all the people who have a contact id that matches the selected users list of contact id's
            //then project the results, this anonymous projection has two properties, the person and the  contact count
            var usersWithMatches = _people
                .Where(x => idsOfContacts.Contains(x.Id))
                .Select(z => new
                    {
                        Person = z, //this is the person record from the database, we'll need to extract display information
                        SharedContactCount = z.Contacts.Count(v => idsOfContacts.Contains(v.Id)) //
                    }).OrderBy(z => z.SharedContactCount)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```